# valueerror: i/o operation on closed file when generating csv file and saving to model in django

Tags: python-2.7, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Here when i am trying to generate csv file and saving to model i am getting "valueerror: i/o operation on closed file"

```
class PaymentReport(View):
def post(self, request):
    client = self.request.user.client
    user = self.request.user
    from_date = request.POST.get('from_date')
    to_date = request.POST.get('to_date')
    with NamedTemporaryFile() as payment_journal:
        
        csv_writer = csv.writer(payment_journal)
        csv_writer.writerow( ['Transaction type','Account reference','Nominal code','Department','Transaction Date'])
        invoice_report = Invoice.objects.filter(client=client,created_at__range=[from_date, to_date],is_self_invoice=True)
        for row in invoice_report:
            
            transaction_type ='Purchase Payment'
            account_reference = '1300'  
            nominal_code ='1200'
            department = 'Forest'
            date = row.created_at.date()
            
          
            
            csv_writer.writerow([transaction_type,account_reference,nominal_code,department,date])
        payment = PaymentDownload.objects.create(client=client,csv_file=File(payment_journal,'payment_download.csv'))  
     
        payment.save()
       
    return redirect(reverse('worker:report_list'))
```

here how can save to my csv file to PaymentDownload table so that i can download it later and my aws bucket is private

Answer (score 0):

The `IO operation on closed file` exception is caused by this block:

```py
with NamedTemporaryFile() as payment_journal:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(payment_journal)
    # ...
payment = PaymentDownload.objects.create(client=client, csv_file=File(payment_journal, 'payment_download.csv'))
```

Because of the dedent, you're using `payment_journal` outside of the `with` block, which corresponds to a context manager. When the end of the `with` block is reached, the file is closed and you can't perform i/o operations on `payment_journal` anymore.